# ffmpeg - live video from rtsp with mp4 fragmented

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

I have the following setup:

- Raspberry 4B (4GB RAM)
- Raspbian 10 (buster)
- ffmpeg 4.1.6

What I want to try:

I want to make a one-to-one video stream from a RTSP stream to my browser, without saving files (like .ts or .m3u), but just push the raw mp4 stream over the network in a HTML5 video tag.

I had already some successes, but it was never a smooth or good video stream, but always stopped and continued.

I used PHP `passthru()` function to call ffmpeg and i piped the video stream on the end

Here are some attempts:

```php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Connection: keep-alive");

passthru("ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i \"rtsp://192.168.0.1:554/livestream/12\" -c:v copy -b:v 2M -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 pipe:");

passthru("ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i \"rtsp://192.168.0.1:554/livestream/12\" -b 1024k -minrate 1024k -bufsize 2048k -r 20 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 pipe:");

passthru("ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.0.1:554/livestream/12 -r 10 -t 60 -movflags frag_keyframe -f mp4 pipe:");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sad no answer until now.

I can tell you why it is not smooth, it is because ffmpeg needs to convert live, and this requires a lot of CPU resources, just passthrough -c copy does not work, because the pipe seems to have limitations compared to copying just to a file.

I have this working on my laptop, CPU goes to 90% (overal)

PU-modus(sen):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Bytevolgorde:                    Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU's:                           8
Online CPU's-lijst:              0-7
Draden per kern:                 2
Kernen per voet:                 4
CPU-voeten:                      1
NUMA-nodes:                      1
Producent-ID:                    GenuineIntel
CPU-familie:                     6
Model:                           140
Modelnaam:                       11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz

I used these arguments for ffmpeg.

```
            "-re", 
            "-rtsp_transport", "tcp", 
            "-max_delay", "30000000",
            "-i", rtspStream,
             "-g", "52",
             "-movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov", 
            "-c:v", "h264",
            "-an",   
            "-f",  "mp4",          
            "-y", "-"
```

The only suggestion I can give to you, make a custom FFMPEG build for Raspberry py, with Neon optimization on. This should give it more power.

https://www.codeinsideout.com/blog/pi/compile-ffmpeg/

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually stopped the project for now but I have found some new method which could work better. I have the PHP-FFMPEG lib which could maybe lower the load and stops the reapeated call of ffmpeg for every client